# text() in R on plot - how to keep on a single line without wrapping?

Tags: r, plot, text, scatter-plot

I often use R to run batch jobs that contain PDF outputs with scatter plots produced using a combination of `plot()` and `points()`, among other graphical functions.  (I don't use ggplot2 much and would like to avoid using it for this question.)

When using the `text()` function in a plot in order to add text near a plotted symbol, I like to use the `pos = 4` option to right-justify text next to say a symbol like `pch = 23` (filled diamond).  But I've noticed that sometimes the text will get wrapped as part of multiple lines, and other times it stays on a single line.  Unfortunately when the lines are wrapped it causes text overlap problems.  Why does `text()` sometimes wrap text on multiple lines?

Is there a way to *force* R to keep the text added to a plot from `text()` on a single line?

Here is my code:

```
text(x=data_frame_w_data_to_plot$x_axis_value,
y=data_frame_w_data_to_plot$y_axis_value, labels=data_frame_w_data_to_plot$text_to_plot, col="black", cex=1, pos=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here.  Found the text string of "\n" just happened to be in one of the cells, and simply used gsub() to slightly modify this cell.  This solved the problem.  Learn from my mistake.  :)

```
data_frame_w_data_to_plot$text_to_plot <- gsub("\n", " ", data_frame_w_data_to_plot$text_to_plot)
```